# Blender game engine touch screen

Tags: scripting, game-engine

I want to make a touchscreen application in the blender game engine.

it's basically an information kiosk type application

Does anyone know of any addons that can detect touch events?

I think I can get by for now with Mouse events, as it's a single touch application.

But any advice or would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to leverage Kivy's event processing with Blender's game engine. It's an entirely Python based framework.